# Mapping days as a 4 digit number!

Tags: cipher, pattern, number-property

I have a puzzle that includes mapping days as a 4 digit number.

- Sunday: 6137
- Monday: 6240
- Tuesday: 7358
- Wednesday: 9497
- Thursday: 85??

The first digit is just the number of characters and the second digit is the nth day starting with Sunday. So the first two digits for Thursday will be 85, but I am not able to figure out the last two digits for Thursday.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I figured it out. It will be 8589.

The first and second digits are explained in the question itself, then we just have to calculate the summation of the squares of the first digit and second digit. i.e 8 * 8 + 5 * 5 = 89.

Comment: Hello @codeingerman, Welcome to PSE. Firstly, when you ask a question, you need to wait a few days for others to answer it. If no one answers it then may be you can give hints or answer it yourself. Secondly, if and when you do answer it you need to use the Spoiler so that folks who want to work on it don't accidently see the answer. Thirdly there is a typo in your answer. It should read 89 not 69.

Comment: @DrD, those only really apply if the puzzle is being set as a challenge for others to solve, whereas here to poster was genuinely asking for help, so they don't have hints etc. to give. Spoilers are optional in this situation.